# create more than one form in a page with word mailing list

Tags: ms-word

I am using ms-word 2007 and ms-excel 2007. I use mailing list to import data from excel file to word file and I should create a form with 21cm width and 9.5 cm height. I want to print every 3 forms in a A4 paper. during printing I can't use 3 pages per sheet(word does not have this item) so I think the only way is to create 3 forms in one page (an A4 paper)... how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution...
It can be done by using ... Mailings > rules > next record.
for first form you should use "insert merge list" as usually. 
for second one in the same page, at first you should click on the "Mailings > rules > next record" then you should use "insert merge list" for second form.
for third one in the same paper again you should repeat second step.
After that, if you print the forms you can see that you have 3 individual forms in every page.